# C# Display All Members of a List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, wcf, textbox

I have a WCF service and a Windows Form.  When the button on the Form is clicked, I want a List (with 4 Members) populated via the Service.  I then want the List displayed on the From with the 4 Members as Columns.

Better yet, I would like to display use each Member as part of a textBox.

Right now, I can only display each Member in a separate listBox.

Here is the code.  GateInfo.cs:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace JimWcfFormTest3
{
    [DataContract]

    public class GateInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int carid { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int paid_at_gate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int wash_pkg_purch { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string carte { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Service1.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace JimWcfFormTest3
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        private List<GateInfo> _gate;

        private Service1()
        {
            _gate = new List<GateInfo>();
        }

        public void Gate_to_Server(GateInfo gatein)
        {
            if (gatein != null) _gate.Add(gatein);
        }

        public List<GateInfo> Server_to_Term()
        {
            return _gate;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int carnum = 2;
    int pay = 1;
    int wash = 5;
    string txt = "TEST";
    var data_out = new GateInfo { carid = carnum, paid_at_gate = pay, wash_pkg_purch = wash, carte = txt };

    server.Gate_to_Server(data_out);

    listBox1.DisplayMember = "carid";
    listBox1.DataSource = server.Server_to_Term();

    listBox4.DisplayMember = "paid_at_gate";
    listBox4.DataSource = server.Server_to_Term();

    listBox5.DisplayMember = "wash_pkg_purch";
    listBox5.DataSource = server.Server_to_Term();

    listBox6.DisplayMember = "carte";
    listBox6.DataSource = server.Server_to_Term();
}
```

Ideally, I would like to display this all in one textBox like so:

"timestamp:  Car=carid, Pay=paid_at_gate, Package = wash_pkg_purch, Ala Carte=carte"

Comment: Drop a `DataGridView` on form and then set a list as `DataSource` of the control, for example `dataGridView1.DataSource = server.Server_to_Term();`

Comment: Also if you want to show `timestamp: Car=carid, Pay=paid_at_gate, Package = wash_pkg_purch, Ala Carte=carte` exactly in a single column, just override `ToString()` method of `GateInfo` class and return desired format.

Comment: @RezaAghaei:  Thanks for the help!  I'm almost there.  I have a follow-up:

When I added the override to my GateInfo class and do this in my Form:

`GateInfo data_out = new GateInfo { carid = carnum, paid_at_gate = pay, wash_pkg_purch = wash, carte = txt };

textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + data_out.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);`

It still returns:

**WindowsFormsApplication1.JimTestServiceRef.GateInfo**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RezaAghaei answered the initial question:

> Drop a DataGridView on form and then set a list as DataSource of the
>   control, for example dataGridView1.DataSource =
>   server.Server_to_Term()

The question of how to do put this all in a text box is answered here:
[How to Override ToString and Display in a textBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851716/c-sharp-override-tostring-and-display-in-textbox)